# Using bootstrap from node_modules folder using gulp (without bower or webpack)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, gulp

I have read through numerous similar resources here but they eiter use bower which is apparently outdated or webpack which I am not going to learn now as the projects i'm working on use gulp. I have my file structure as follow:

```
      - Project
        - /src
           - /scss
           - /js
           - /img
           - .index.html
        - /dist
        - /node_modules
           - /bootstrap
             -/dist
               - /css
               - /js
        - .package.json
        - .gulfile.js
```

1. How do I get to work with both the bootstrap css and the js from the node_modules folder in my src/ index.html file.(obviously at the end I would like to still just use`<script src="js/bootstrap.js"><?script> or better compiled <script src="js/main.js"><?script>`)
2. How do i then compile it to the dist folder with both bootstrap components still available for production.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Since it looks like you are using scss, you can simply import the main Bootstrap file into yours

should be something like

`@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';`

For the JS part of Bootstrap, you could simply write a gulp task that concatenates your script and the Bootstrap one together. You can easily achieve this using packages like [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)!

Comment: this is not at all answering my question and i don't think this is the correct way doing this as you cannot do this with the js. Reading on other post you don't want to expose your path via the script tag so it has to get some kind of gulp task to run in order to get this to work properly.